# Need Help Name Bidding on Premium Names

Tags: nodeos, cleos, naming

So I've seen on several explorers that people are already bidding on names. It seems like I remember watching a video where someone was talking about Premium names and how you could have the equivalent of a .com on the EOS blockchain, but instead it could be IDK .history or .grace or whatever you want it to be. Then people with a domain name on a hosting service can direct their domain name to you premium name. So for example it would be ancientrome.history.

If this is what I think it is, then I definitely want to bid on some names. I see in CLEOS when you type in **./cleos system -h** that there are actions for **BIDNAME** and **BIDNAMEINFO** but I keep getting errors when I put in a NEWNAME after I enter BIDNAMEINFO and wondered if I need NODEOS set up (which I haven't done yet) or if I'd have to use a Block Producers node to bid on some names?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a BP node to bid on some names.

```
$ cleos -u https://user-api.eoseoul.io:443 system bidnameinfo hello
bidname:                             hello
highest bidder:               ha4daobxg4ge
highest bid:                             1
last bid time:     2018-06-10T14:33:25.500
```

Comment: Ok so the names that are being bidded on are just account names then?

Comment: All users have the same rules for bidding; BPs don't get special treatment. Names that begin with `.` will never be biddable because that's not needed. If you win the bid for `com`, then you become the registrar for names which end with `.com` automatically.